# Qual diferença em executeQuery() e executeUpdate()?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, jdbc

Qual a diferença e quando devo usar `executeQuery()` ou `executeUpdate()`?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 9):

Imagino eu que é seja sem o ponto, se for com o ponto teria que descobrir do que está falando.

[`executeQuery()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) como o próprio nome diz, é para consultas, quase sempre usa-se um `SELECT` nele e um resultado será retornado com os dados, ou um erro.

[`executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) como o próprio nome diz, é para atualizações, deve-se usar um comando de escrito como `INSERT`, `UPDATE` e `DELETE`, e ele retorna o que foi afetado e não um resultado de dados.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).